# Should one admit to a policy violation made out of ignorance?

Tags: united-states

My company has a personal trading policy, and as an employee I intend to follow all trading restrictions placed on me. However, one of the requirements ---that I discovered recently--- was that all trading accounts should be reported within a certain number of days of opening and not doing so is a policy violation. I was genuinely unaware of it, since the actual clause was embedded in a policy document and not covered in regular compliance trainings.

If I had trading accounts that otherwise fulfill the trading restrictions but have not been reported for some months, what would be the best course of action for me?

I could admit an honest mistake and report those accounts immediately.

Alternatively I could close those accounts immediately.

Finally, I could keep the accounts open.

I don't really have a way to find out how big a deal this is and whether admitting to a policy violation will be held against me.

Comment: Did you actually trade when you were not supposed too or is this just about a delay in notification ?

Comment: Just a delay in notification. I don't believe I violated any trading restrictions.

Comment: Or just report them without admitting anything's and leave explanations for later.

Comment: Do you work in the securities industry where insider trading is a risk?

Comment: For other countries I would have closed this as "you need a lawyer", but since you are in the US, with a good chance at being employed "at will", I don't see how a lawyer could help you here. They could fire you. For this reason or any other, or none at all. You have no protections. So I will vote to close this as opinion based, since without any indication what your company is like, your guess at the best option is as good as anyone's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends if you want to keep the accounts or not, you haven't violated any other restrictions using them so it's not a huge deal yet, just a misunderstanding.

I think you should either report them and explain only if asked.

Alternatively, delete them and hope no one asks.

If you are asked in either case, just explain as you have here. There is no point in drawing attention to the fact you're reporting late and inviting enquiry.